# Как сделать свое собственное Автодополнение/автозаменение?

Tags: php, phpstorm, jetbrains

Привет всем )) 
У меня случилась беда! Вдруг перестало работать несколько клавиш на клавиатуре, и как раз самые нужные. Заменю клаву уже после нового года, но сейчас нужно как то работать!

Подскажите, возможно ли в `phpStorm` с**делать что то типа своего собственного Автодополнение/автозаменение, то есть я ввожу, например, `+/-`, а оно автоматически заменяет данное сочетание на нужной мне символ** ??

Очень прошу помощи )))

Comment: Может быть Live templates подойдут? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/live-templates.html

Comment: **Live templates** подойдет, на крайний случай есть **Виртуальаня клавиатура Windows**

Comment: @artspb, Live templates самое удобное решение) Спасибо

Comment: @Adobe  
Live templates - идеальное решение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вижу два варианта:

- средства ОС - возможно встроеные или внешние, например для Mac OS есть TextExpander
- LiveTemplate в IDE. Preferences -> Editor -> Live Templates -> plain и можете добавить свои шаблоны. По умолчанию они срабатывают по клавише Tab

Comment: Спасибо ! `LiveTemplate` - для меня лучший вариант )